# How to split a df into smaller df's based on the unique values in one column, then pivot each df over another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I was looking to provide year on year reporting based on Year_Month and various measure like volume and count of done trades. The following allowed appropriate formatting for a much larger dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfTest = [
             ('Client', ['A','A','A','A',
                         'B','B','B','B',
                         'C','C','C','C',
                         'D','D','D','D']),
            ('Year_Month', ['2018-08', '2018-08', '2018-10','2018-11',
                             '2018-08', '2018-08', '2018-10','2018-11',
                             '2018-08', '2018-08', '2018-10', '2018-11',
                             '2018-08', '2018-08', '2018-10', '2018-11']),
            ('Volume', [100, 200, 300,400,
                        1, 2, 3,4,
                        10, 20, 30,40,
                        1000, 2000, 3000,4000]
            ),
            ('state', ['Done', 'Tied Done', 'Tied Done','Done',
                       'Passed', 'Done', 'Passed', 'Done',
                       'Rejected', 'Done', 'Passed', 'Done',
                       'Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Done']
            )
          ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(dfTest)
print(df)
```

Sample data

```
   Client Year_Month  Volume      state
0       A    2018-08     100       Done
1       A    2018-08     200  Tied Done
2       A    2018-10     300  Tied Done
3       A    2018-11     400       Done
4       B    2018-08       1     Passed
5       B    2018-08       2       Done
6       B    2018-10       3     Passed
7       B    2018-11       4       Done
8       C    2018-08      10   Rejected
9       C    2018-08      20       Done
10      C    2018-10      30     Passed
11      C    2018-11      40       Done
12      D    2018-08    1000       Done
13      D    2018-08    2000       Done
14      D    2018-10    3000       Done
15      D    2018-11    4000       Done
```

Comment: So what is you question ? You already have a solution right ?

Comment: Yes sharing the knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spit df into smaller df's based on Client

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Client')))
print(d)
print("")

# Print each split df
for i in d.values():
    print(i, '\n')
    print("")
```

Pivot each df based on Year_Month and volume

```
for i in d.values():
    volume = pd.pivot_table(data=i,
                         values='Volume',
                         index=['Client'],
                         columns=['Year_Month'],
                         aggfunc= sum
                         ).reset_index().fillna(0)
    print(volume, '\n')
    print("")


   Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
    0               A      300      300      400 


    Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
    0               B        3        3        4 


    Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
    0               C       30       30       40 


    Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
    0               D     3000     3000     4000
```

Pivot each df based on Year_Month and count of trades

```
for i in d.values():
    count = pd.pivot_table(data=i,
                         values='Volume',
                         index=['Client'],
                         columns=['Year_Month'],
                         aggfunc= np.count_nonzero
                         ).reset_index().fillna(0)
    print(count, '\n')

Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
0               A        2        1        1 


Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
0               B        2        1        1 


Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
0               C        2        1        1 


Year_Month Client  2018-08  2018-10  2018-11
0               D        2        1        1
```